# How to modify the framerate on android

Tags: android, frame-rate

I'm developing an android app to send the live Video & Audio stream to other PC, the app can capture the camera and mic and send the live stream and use VLC player to play it, it works very well in my htc s710e(android version 4.0.4), but in other mobile it's very choppy. I tested many mobiles, some mobile's hardware is higher than s710e, and some is lower than it, but all of them are very choppy.

I debugged it for too many time and found I cannot modify the frame rate of video, although I set the frame rate is 10 or 15, but the live video in vlc shows the frame rate is 30(H.263).

So how can I modify the frame rate? hope someone can helps me, thank you.

Comment: I found someone met the same question, and they said that **some android device cannot modify their frame rate**, is that true?<br/>I played the live stream by VLC player on my PC, and found the frame rate is fixed, 30!!!, although I set it is 10 in my app.

Comment: I found someone met the same question, and they said that **some android device cannot modify their frame rate**, is that true?  I played the live stream by VLC player on my PC, and found the frame rate is fixed, 30!!!, although I set it is 10 in my app.  I think the frame rate is not the only reason, because all of mobiles I cheacked are the same frame rate(30), but HTC s710e works very well and others are too choppy.